# Ubuntu 18.04 Cant access Internet

Tags: networking

Got the above installed and running services like DHCP and DNS. DHCP works well however I notice that this server cannot ping the internet. It can ping the gateway and the gateway can ping the internet however the Ubuntu host server cannot ping any ip address on the internet. Since it cannot ping its DNS server - 8.8.8.8 clients using this DNS server cannot access internet. Those client however can ping 8.8.8.8

my netplan configuration

```
root@ubuntu_srv:~# cat /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml


# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    ethernets:
        ens3:
            addresses: [192.168.8.11/24]
            gateway4: 192.168.8.1
            nameservers:
              addresses: [8.8.8.8]
            dhcp4: false
    version: 2
```

Any help will be really appreciated

Comment: Try adding 'nameserver 8.8.8.8' into /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: @JohnRonald Ive added that to no avail.Could be something to do with this Ubuntu cannot routing ? By the way  I've got dnsmasq installed for DNS and DHCP.